# SSRS/Visual Studio Issues with week grouping on a graph

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

I have a query about line charts (or probably charts in general!). New user of both SQL and SSRS and from an Excel only background so please bear with me!

I have a line graph which plots the weeks of my results from a set data. The results within the data work from a 'To' and 'From' parameter, and when looking between dates such as 01/01/2017 - 28/02/2017 all is fine.

When however I try and get the data looking at 01/12/2016 to 28/02/2017, the following sequence appears and I cannot figure out how to get this going from Weeks 51 52 53 1 2 3 4 5

The sequence is 0 20 40 and the line graph seem to back on itself as a result.  Unfortunately as I have a low reputation due to being a relatively new users I cannot provide a picture of the graph

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

You need to order your series by both year and week.

Hard to give more information without a picture or dataset example, but that's the principle of handling days/weeks over multiple years.

Comment: Hi Bish.  I had already done that and it hasn't worked. What further info could i give you to help deconstruct this problem?  Is it worth me re-editing my original question with the information you may need?

Comment: @Wil-Liam Are you able to post links to an image hosting site to show the current set up? How about some sample data?

Comment: This is sorted now, apologies for lack of info previously.  I have used the Horizontal Axis Properties, changed from Scarlar to Category, used an interval expression of '=1' and it seems to worked a treat